# Contacts not seen

Tags: whatsapp

I Installed Whatsapp on my Lumia 730 few hours back.But I am getting the message that none if my contacts are using Whatsapp. The contact picture & Status is coming blank for everybody.How can this issue be resolved ?

Comment: Did you used whatsapp with the same phone number in other device? This is your brand new device and first installation of whatsapp in this?

Comment: Have you tried going to the favorites pivot and clicking refresh from the menu?